# [ms access]'s listbox on visible off still runs?

Tags: ms-access

i have a tab and has few pages on this tab control (say 8 pages) and each page has 2 or 3 listbox displaying some info related to that job (sales, admin, warehouse etc).

when a staff login, only the page related to their job is showing (tab page visible = false) and wondering if those listbox's row source still active (but not showing due to visible put to false)?

just wondering if affects performance due to many listbox in a form, visible or not?

thanks for reading.

Comment: If by 'active' you mean the listbox RowSource is queried, I would guess yes. I don't know any way to verify. Unless reduced performance can actually be observed, I would say it is a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Controls that are on an active, loaded form (even if they, or even the entire form, are/is not visible) can be queried against, period. Doesn't matter if they are on another tab or not. So yes, they will affect performance (likely negligibly, unless you've got thousands of or extremely complicated look-ups going on).

Answer (score 0):

If the parent container(i.e a page on the tab is not visible), then all controls on the page will not be visible.

A control not visible in this instance because the parent container is not, e.g listbox, combo box, textbox, etc, does not consume memory space.

Comment: many thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that the control is not loaded and therefore not holding a value, which is incorrect. Invisible controls absolutely *can* be queried against, I do it all the time. Which means memory *is* used to store their values.

Comment: No, i didn't imply that, controls not been visible, can still hold values, i implied that memory space is less consumed when the controls are not visible

Comment: You can check the article on this link, though it refers to hiding forms.  https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/loading-and-keeping-forms-hidden.html, here emphasis is on performance and not memory usage. All controls be it visible or not can consume memory, because they are available for the runtime to access.

Comment: i see. so i think i will re-design the code to run the query only when the tab page is activated for that job. thanks for further clarifying my doubts.